# Initial route visible behind transparent Flutter page

Tags: flutter

I have an (Android-only) Flutter app where some additional activities start the app with a different route than the normal launch.

```kotlin
class ExtraActivity : FlutterActivity() {

  override fun getInitialRoute(): String = "/extra"

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    intent.putExtra("route", getInitialRoute())
    intent.putExtra("background_mode", "transparent")
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
  }

  //...
}
```

There's no problem with that, the app starts with `/extra` instead of the normal initial route of `/` – at least visually. But if I make the activity transparent as above (also making sure the Flutter page itself is transparent or at least translucent) it reveals that the `/extra` page actually appears stacked over the `/` initial route. Also, if I pop the `/extra` page, it returns to the `/` page. While I can modify this second behavior, I can't help the visual problem, the initial page being visible below the transparent second page. Is there any way to force the `/extra` initial route to appear without the original route also being present?

Answer (score 0):

As insane as it might sound, I think I found the solution by pure happenstance. If I rename my `initialRoute` to something other than `/`, say `/home`, it works. The name `/` must be hardwired somewhere to have special treatment. Go figure...